# Selecting observations in range of numbers between set of other numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a character variable in the dataset that reads as '2-6' or '4-7'.
What I am interested in selecting those observations where the numbers 3,4,5 may be in that spectrum '4-7'
it is easy enough to use the statement

```
where 3 between TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+',1,1)) and TO_NUMBER(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'(-)\d+',1,1),2)) or
 4 between TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+',1,1)) and TO_NUMBER(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'(-)\d+',1,1),2)) or 
 5 between TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+',1,1)) and TO_NUMBER(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'(-)\d+',1,1),2))
```

Just looking to see if there is a more..eloquent solution as to group that range together in a function-
test data below
TIA-

```
with test (id, MEAS_VALUE) as (
  select 1,'2-5'                   from dual union all --want this
  select 2,'1-2'                from dual union all   --do not want this
  select 3,'5-7'  from dual)   ----want this
  select * from test
  where 3 between TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+',1,1)) and TO_NUMBER(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'(-)\d+',1,1),2)) 
   or 4 between TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+',1,1)) and TO_NUMBER(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'(-)\d+',1,1),2)) or 
     5 between TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+',1,1)) and TO_NUMBER(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'(-)\d+',1,1),2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE, '\d+', 1, 1)) as lo,
             TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE, '\d+', 1, 2)) as lhi
      from test t
     ) t
where 3 between lo and hi and
      4 between lo and hi and
      5 between lo and hi;
```

You can further simplify the condition to:

```
where least(3, 4, 5) >= lo and
      greatest(3, 4, 5) <= hi
```

Comment: putting  the regexp_substr  as lo/hi does give it better readability -however the last part of your code w/ the least or greatest components  does not get all the observations.

Comment: @LawrenceBlock . . . I'm pretty sure that logic should be the same.